# Easy way to cast an object array into another type in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to be able to be able to quickly cast an array of objects to a different type, such as String, but the following code doesn't work:

```
String[] a = new String[2];
a[0] = "Hello";
a[1] = "World";
ArrayList b = new ArrayList(a);
String[] c = (String[]) b.ToArray();
```

And I don't want to have to do this:

```
String[] a = new String[2];
a[0] = "Hello";
a[1] = "World";
ArrayList b = new ArrayList(a);
Object[] temp = b.ToArray();
String[] c = new String[temp.Length];
for(int i=0;i<temp.Length;i++)
{
    c[i] = (String) temp[i];
}
```

Is there an easy way to do this without using a temporary variable?
Edit: This is in ASP.NET, by the way.

Comment: Man, how long will it take for people to stop using `ArrayList`?

Comment: Hey, I'm still new to C#. What should I use instead?

Comment: Use generic collections in place of ArrayList. Generics are completely type-safe in a way that ArrayList could never possibly be.

Comment: I hope my comment wasn't taken the wrong way. It is just one of my pet peeves.

Comment: It's actually a very good questions and generics sometimes don't help at all. Let's say you have a generic piece of code running on an List<object> and a more specific one requiring a List<string>. Now another piece of code uses both methods. How would you do that? Even if you use generics all over the shop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best solution would be to use a `List<string>`.

Comment: ...and welcome to a new world ;) It's seriously worth getting your head around generics.

Answer (score 4):

Use LINQ:

```
String[] c = b.Cast<String>().ToArray();
```

May I ask why you're using `ArrayList` in the first place, instead of a generic collection type?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
myArray.Select(mySomething => new SomethingElse(mySomething)).ToArray()
```

to cast it to anything you like :)

Answer (score 0):

+1 for the generic Collections such as `List<T>`, -1 for `ArrayList` which is better be put on mothballs.